# IIS restarts suspended aplications after configuration change

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool

I have encountered a (mis?)behavior of IIS/ASP.NET related to app pool suspension (Idle Worker Process Page-Out), and I can't find documentation about it. When an ASP.NET app (.NET Framework 4.8) in IIS (10.0) is suspended, and then a change is made to IIS configuration, the next time the app is accessed, it restarts (new AppDomain in same w3wp process).

It doesn't matter What is changed in IIS (appcmd add apppool, appcmd add app, etc.). Even touching applicationhost.config (changing LastWriteTime without content change) is enought to fire a restart. To be clear, the restart only happens if the app is SUSPENDED when IIS configuration is changed, and not if the app is live.

We have a lot of apps in the same IIS server, with frequent app deployments, and each time a deployment is made, all the suspended apps are affected (next user must wait the restart time). This renders useless the suspension mechanism. ¿Is this restart behavior by design or it's a bug? ¿Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: What do you mean by "suspended"? As far as I know, IIS sites can be running or stopped, and they won't magically restart on a config change.

Comment: By "suspension" I mean this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/idle-worker-process-page-out-in-iis85

Comment: Check this setting https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NVez.png  If it is set to true, maybe configuration change causes application pool recycle. Otherwise, I think it is by design.

Comment: I have tried that setting, no luck.